# mdf new page and border not coming properly

Tags: php, mpdf

Im using mdf but the border and new line not coming properly
how can i specify new page and also the constant border style for each page?

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4','','',10,10,10,10,10,10); 
$mpdf->mirrorMargins = 0;   // Use different Odd/Even headers and footers and mirror margins
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

[image]